# magit-stash-create: Cannot save the current index state

Tags: magit, git

I'm using magit 20160517.838, Emacs 25.0.50.2

I just upgraded magit from 20160320 to 20160517 and when I try to stash I now get this issue;

```
magit-stash-create: Cannot save the current index state
```

I can still manually stash on the command line with

```
git stash
```

**Update**

I've put the debug into my init.el file

```
(setq magit-git-debug t)
```

Then I restarted emacs and tried stashing again but no debug console is displayed. I get the following error in my *magit-process file.

```
128 git … commit-tree --no-gpg-sign -m index on master: 917b40b Revert "electric-pair-mode failed with python files." -p HEAD 8e2cbf3020c9c4d509f98a1924f3d43ba0ed4f12
fatal: Not a valid object name --no-gpg-sign
```

I think I require updating my git as I'm running an old version '1.9.1'

Comment: Do `(setq magit-git-debug t)` and then use `$` to see whether you get a more useful error message in the process buffer.

Comment: The failing command is `git commit-tree`.

Comment: If you don't help me help you, then I have nothing to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed [Magit does require at least Git v1.9.4](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/I-am-using-a-Git-release-older-than-v194.html).

Comment: I am using git 1.9.4, and I also get this error: `fatal: Not a valid object name --no-gpg-sign`.

Answer (score 8):

This could also be due to not having configured git properly:

```
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```